# How do I reproduce Relax NG rules in C++ objects?

Tags: c++, schema, relaxng

At the momemet I am working on part of my application where I need to parse Relax NG schema and reproduce rules within file in C++ objects. I start with example code so I can explain better.

> ```
> <!-- property.element -->
> <define name="property.element">
>     <element name="property">
>         <attribute name="type" />
>         <interleave>
>             <zeroOrMore>
>                 <ref name="resource.class" />
>             </zeroOrMore>
>             <ref name="literal.class" />
>         </interleave>
>     </element>
> </define>
> ```

I want to create object where I can store information like:

- [define] name,
- element name,
- attribute names,
- allowed child elements with associated rules (zero or more, one or more).

Then I want to display all possible elements in my GUI where I can add only valid (in terms of Relax NG schema) elements to tree-like structure. For example - I can add only resource.class or literal.class to my property.element, every other possible element is greyed in my GUI when I have selected property.element node in GUI. I use Qt, so I load schema into QDomDocument to get access to DOM tree.

Such mechanism has to be universal i.e. no matter how elements are named, or how its structure is. In my draft I created simple class where I placed several members like: defined_name, element_name, required_attributes, optional_attributes. Currently I am stuck because I do not have any idea how to represent rules in C++ class. If I had constant set of objects on which I work I would hard-code every object, but my objects set is very likely to change drastically over time. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: one _rule_ base class and N derived classes (_zeroOrMore_ and so on, one for each known rule). Alternatively one generic _rule_ class (with a _rule_name_ member that maps to node name).

Answer (score 0):

Convert the RNG file to XSD using TRANG, then convert the XSD to c++ using CodeSynthesis either XSD or XSDe). There are a bunch of samples with XSDe, so there might be one demonstrating how to validate the xml input with the schema rules.

http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/trang.html
http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsde/

Comment: The mailing list post http://www.codesynthesis.com/pipermail/xsd-users/2010-November/003080.html with subject "autogenerate graphical user interface (GUI in QT)", might be interesting regarding the need of a Qt GUI.